# Flutter - MaterialButton not changing when saved inside of List

Tags: flutter, dart

My goal is that I can display a dynamic amount of buttons which change color when they are clicked.

I have found [this example](https://inducesmile.com/google-flutter/how-to-change-button-background-color-in-flutter/) and it works normally. I then tried to extend it in a way that I can have more than one button, but it stops changing the color.

However on the first loading the initial color is loaded. This made me curious and I have tried to save the state of the clicks in a singleton and load it on opening the screen (instead of creating a new state of the clicks). Then it loads the color which should be displayed.

It looks like this: clicking the buttons 1 and 3 -- it stays [unchanged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAl8l.png) - after closing and reopening [the color is changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QOPt.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'singleton.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => new _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  int btnCount = 6;
  List<MaterialButton> buttonList;
  List<int> colorIndexes;
  List<List<Color>> colorList;

  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    colorList = _createColorList(btnCount);
    matrixButtons = _createButtonList(btnCount);

    if(Singleton().test != null)  // with this the right color is loaded but only after closing and reopening the screen
      colorIndexes = Singleton().test;
    else
      colorIndexes = _createColorIndexes(btnCount);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Button List"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              for(RaisedButton btn in buttonList) btn,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _circleColor(index){
    int maxLength = colorList[index].length;
    setState(() {
      colorIndexes[index] += 1;
      if(colorIndexes[index] >= maxLength)
        colorIndexes[index] = 0;
    });
    Singleton().test = colorIndexes;
  }

  List<RaisedButton> _createButtonList(int btnCount){
    List<RaisedButton> returnList = new List<RaisedButton>();
    for(int i = 0; i < btnCount; i++){
      returnList.add(new RaisedButton(
        child: Text(i.toString()),
        onPressed: (){
          _circleColor(i);
        },
        color: colorList[i][colorIndexes[i]],
      ));
    }
    return returnList;
  }

  List<int> _createColorIndexes(int btnCount){
    List<int> returnList = new List<int>();
    for(int i = 0; i < btnCount; i++){
      returnList.add(0);
    }
    return returnList;
  }

  List<List<Color>> _createColorList(int btnCount){
    List<List<Color>> returnList = new List<List<Color>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < btnCount; i++){
      List<Color> tmp = [ //Get list of colors
        Colors.blue,
        Colors.green,
        Colors.red
      ];
      returnList.add(tmp);
    }
    return returnList;
  }

}
```

**Edit:** Complete code.

The singleton just consists of a basic structure:

```
class Singleton {
  static final Singleton _singleton = Singleton._internal();
  Singleton._internal();
  var test;
  factory Singleton() { return _singleton; }
}
```

The starting point is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'test_screen.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => new _MainScreenState();
}


class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen>{
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("flutter_app"),   //TODO - change this
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new MaterialButton(
              child: Text("click"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TestScreen()));
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This is because a list is immutable. You have to modify a copy of it using `List.from()`.

Comment: Where do you mean that i should use the ```List.from()```? Should I copy the list, then modify it and override it? If you mean that - how is it possible to do something like that? (I'm pretty new to Flutter so sorry if it's something obvious)

Answer (score 0):

Seems your widget tree is not updating itself. Try using keys in your Raised Button widget. So if list view's data will change keys will change and Widget tree will be notified to update button.

If it was not useful then please post your full code.

Comment: I'm pretty new to flutter so I don't know what you mean with using the keys - i've added some keys but it doesn't seem to work. Also, it's pretty much the whole code - i've added the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for the problem.

The comment of jared (that the List is immutable) got me the idea that i simply replace the button each time he circles through the colors. I also noticed that the List inside the List for the colors is useless because it always is the same.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => new _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  int btnCount = 6;
  List<MaterialButton> buttonList= new List<MaterialButton>();
  List<int> colorStates= new List<int>();
  List<Color> colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.green
  ];

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    for(int i = 0; i < btnCount; i++){
      colorStates.add(0);
      buttonList.add(
        new MaterialButton(
          child: Text(i.toString()),
          onPressed: (){_circleColor(i);},
          color: colors[colorStates[i]],
        )
      );
    }
  }

  _circleColor(int index){
    setState(() {
      colorStates[index] += 1;
      if(colorStates[index] >= colors.length)
        colorStates[index] = 0;
        buttonList[index] = new MaterialButton(
          child: Text(index.toString()),
          onPressed: () { _circleColor(index); },
          color: colors[colorStates[index]],
        );
    });
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Button List"),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              for(var btn in buttonList) btn,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```